# Do I have to use the /g flag in these subroutine calls?

Tags: regex, recursion, subroutine

```
^Name:\ (.*)\r?\n
Born:\ (?'date'(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|[1-9])
            -(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)
            -(?:19|20)[0-9][0-9])\r?\n
Admitted:\ \g'date'\r?\n
Released:\ \g'date'$
```

The example is from here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html (bottom of the third section there)

I know that `/g` is a flag for "global" but there is no good info about it on the Net. Is this something necessary in this example, or do I always have to use it when referring to named capturing groups? Can I omit it here and it will work the same way? I just don't understand how it works.

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove `\g` (the subrouting syntax)? It is not related to a global flag. If you remove `\g` the regex will stop working since no group pattern will be recursed.

Comment: To answer the question, please provide some sample text, expected output and what you tried.

Comment: All that is needed is on the above site / page.

Comment: "You can remember this by the fact that the \g syntax is a Ruby invention, later copied by PCRE." - https://www.regular-expressions.info/recursecapture.html

Comment: The "Regex sub-expressions" part - https://idiosyncratic-ruby.com/11-regular-extremism.html - Would this be it?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/hv0szh - Also - http://prntscr.com/hv0t9g - from - https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrecurse.html

Comment: `\g<NUMBER>` / `\g<GROUP_NAME>` is a recursion construct (that applies a group pattern recursively, or just "repeats" the group pattern to avoid using a part of the pattern more than once) that was first used in Oniguruma regex engine. Then, the same was added to PCRE library "for compatibility", in addition to `(?NUMBER)` / `(?&GROUPNAME)` PCRE syntax. `\g'date'` != `'date'`.

Answer (score 0):

The `\g` construct is a Oniguruma (Pcre) function call.
And, as that link shows, it is the same as any modern engine function call.

Note that, if the same function is called inside that same function
it is known as *Recursion*. Which is the same as any language.

In your example though, it is just re-using the existing expression
in the *`date`* group (which is group 2 here).
And so, it's just a function call.

[Formatted:](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
 ^ 
 Name:\ 
 ( .* )                        # (1)
 \r? \n 
 Born:\ 
 (?'date'                      # (2 start)
      (?: 3 [01] | [12] [0-9] | [1-9] )
      -
      (?:
           Jan
        |  Feb
        |  Mar
        |  Apr
        |  May
        |  Jun
        |  Jul
        |  Aug
        |  Sep
        |  Oct
        |  Nov
        |  Dec
      )
      -
      (?: 19 | 20 )
      [0-9] [0-9] 
 )                             # (2 end)
 \r? \n 
 Admitted:\  \g'date' \r? \n 
 Released:\  \g'date' 
 $
```

Metrics:

```
----------------------------------
 * Format Metrics
----------------------------------
Cluster Groups               =   3

Capture Groups               =   2
       Named                 =   1

Recursions                   =   2
       \g Oniguruma (Pcre)   =   2

Character Classes            =   6
```

Comment: Is there any description of this on the Net. "oniguruma function call pcre" does not show any good results.

Comment: I am not sure but it seems like the answer may be not correct.

Comment: @ThomasMorgan - Well, I guess my answer is useless... Using google with `oniguruma function call pcre` yeilds this https://embedthis.com/appweb/doc/man/regexp.html
`For  compatibility with Oniguruma, the non-Perl syntax \g followed by a
       name or a number enclosed either in angle brackets or single quotes, is
       an  alternative  syntax for referencing a subpattern as a "subroutine".`